# How do I find the surface area of this function: $y = tan^{-1}x$

Tags: integration

Consider the function for $0 \leq x \leq 2$:

$$y = \tan^{-1}x$$

Using the formula:

$$SA = \int 2 \pi y L\, dx$$

where $y = \text{radius of the frustum}$, and $L$ is the arc length: $ L = \int \sqrt{1 + (\frac{dy}{dx})^2}$ where

\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac1{ 1 + x^2 } & &\text{so that} & \left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2 = \frac1{x^4 + 2x^2 + 1}
\end{align}

But I'm stuck here. I'm still left with:

$$SA = 2 \pi \int_0^2 \tan^{-1}x  \cdot \sqrt{ 1 + \frac{1}{x^4 + 2x^2 + 1}} 
 \,dx$$

Where do I even go from here? What can I do with the inverse tan still in my equation?

Should I just use x actually instead of $tan^{-1}x$?

Comment: I have the feeling that I saw this problem earlier today. In my humble opinion, just use numerical integration.

Comment: What do you mean by that? How do I get rid of the $tan^{-1}x$? I dont understand what that means @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: I just think that there is no way to get an analytical result for this integral.

Comment: But I want to know if I set this integral up correctly. I'm still leaving a tan^{-1}x in the setup. I can use a CAD, but I want to know if I did this setup correctly.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici does that make sense? Leaving the $tan^{-1}x$ feels weird...

Answer (score 1):

$$S=2\pi\int_0^2\arctan(x)\sqrt{1-\frac1{(x^2+1)^2}}dx$$
Let $x=\tan u$ so $dx=\sec^2(u)du$:
$$S=2\pi\int_0^{a}u\sqrt{1-\frac1{(\tan^2(u)+1)^2}}\sec^2(u)du$$
Where $a=\arctan2$. We have 
$$S=2\pi\int_0^a u\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos^4(u)}}{\cos^2(u)}du$$
$$S=2\pi\int_0^a u\sqrt\frac{1-\cos^4(u)}{\cos^4(u)}du$$
$$S=2\pi\int_0^a u\sqrt{\sec^4(u)-1}du$$
At this point, [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%202pi*xsqrt(sec%5E4(x)-1)dx) gives a monstrous result for the antiderivative including a bunch of $\log$ functions and a few $\mathrm{Li}_2$ functions. So in theory there is a closed form, but realistically, the best you can do is numerical approximation, and from the [Integral Calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=2pixsqrt%28sec%5E4%28x%29-1%29&lbound=0&ubound=arctan%282%29&numonly=1), we have $$S\approx 7.622399360811291...$$
Although there may be a closed form in terms of a special value of a hypergeometric function... I will update if I find one.

Comment: I suppose that *monstrous* is just an understatement ! In any manner $\to +1$ (may I cinfess that I gave up before starting ?). Cheers :-)